# How can one find the Unicode codepoints that a font has glyphs for, on a Debian-based system?

Tags: python, ruby, unicode, fonts, fontconfig

From a scripting language (Python or Ruby, say) on a Debian-based system, I would like to find either one of:

1. All the Unicode codepoints that a particular font has glyphs for
2. All the fonts that have glyphs for a particular Unicode codepoint

(Obviously either 1 or 2 can be derived form the other, so whatever is easier would be great.)  I have done this in the past by running:

```
fc-list : file charset
```

... and parsing the output at the end of each line, based on [this code from fontconfig](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/tree/src/fccharset.c#n803)
but it seems to me that there ought to be a much simpler way of doing this.

(I'm not completely sure this is the right StackExchange site for this question, but I am looking for an answer that can be used programmatically.)

Comment: "There ought to be a simpler way"? Do you know how many font formats there are? And you want to be able to processes *all* of them?!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I know (of course!) that there are many different font formats, but we have libraries that deal with that - for example, the fontconfig command I gave in the question does give you the information I'm after for fonts of several different formats.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-font-supports

Comment: This python script works great : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268286/26952

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try any of the [FreeType 2 language bindings](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/projects.html#bindings). Here's a Perl solution to list the Unicode code points of a font using `Font::FreeType`:

```
use Font::FreeType;
Font::FreeType->new->face('DejaVuSans.ttf')->foreach_char(sub {
    printf("%04X\n", $_->char_code);
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's very helpful - I'll wait a little before ticking "accept" in case there are other answers.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn’t seem to notice glyphs that are allocated to private use areas, like alternate swashes?

Comment: No, but it's certainly not a problem rooted in the Perl bindings. From a quick glance at the freetype2 source code, maybe [`find_unicode_charmap`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/src/base/ftobjs.c#n973) chooses the wrong charmap?

Comment: To install the module on Debian/Ubuntu systems: `sudo apt install libfont-freetype-perl`.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently listed the mapping from unicode codepoints to glypths in a TTF using [TTX/FontTools](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools/). That tool is written in Python, so it matches the Python tag in your post. The command

```
ttx -t cmap foo.ttf
```

will generate an XML file `foo.ttx` which describes that mapping, for various environments and encodings. See e.g. [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6cmap.html) for a description of what the platform and encoding identifiers actually mean. I assume that the package can be used as a library as well as a command line tool, but I have no experience there.