# How to check which fonts contain a specific character with perl?

Tags: perl, fonts

Here are already questions:

- [How to determine which fonts contain a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604855/how-to-determine-which-fonts-contain-a-specific-character)
- [Checking if certain characters are supported by a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274311/checking-if-certain-characters-are-supported-by-a-font)

I have many different fonts. Many of them are "ascii only", and i need to check what fonts contains several accented characters. (latin - unicode codepoints - texts are encoded as utf8) like: (áäčďéěíĺľňóôöőŕřšťúůüűýž)

Have mainly:

- TrueType fonts (with the extension .ttf)
- TrueType collections (extension .ttc)
- OpenType fonts (.otf)

What is the usual (correct) way to do this with perl? (it is the only language what i know a bit and the above questions are for C).  Asking before I start install all CPAN modules what contains "font":).

I'm on OS X (if this is matters, and can install any macports package - if it helps).

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896493/how-can-one-find-the-unicode-codepoints-that-a-font-has-glyphs-for-on-a-debian/15905540#15905540).

Comment: @nwellnhof  Unfortunately, i'm unable install `Font::FreeType` on OS X. Compiling the FreeType.xs throwing error. Fortunately the @mob 's suggetion `Font::TTF` installed cleanly. Thank you anyway, good to know, than here is another solution.

Comment: Not perl, but for SEO sake, this python script works great : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268286/26952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .ttf files, you can use [`Font::TTF`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Font::TTF) and related modules:

```
use Font::TTF::Font;
my $font = Font::TTF::Font->open( "C:/Windows/Fonts/ariali.ttf" );
my @supported_codepoints = sort { $a <=> $b } $font->{cmap}->reverse;
```

I'm getting out of my depth, but there's also a `Font::TTF::Ttc` module in the `Font::TTF` distribution that you could poke around in and see if you can extract more information about supported code points.

(`Font::TTF` suggestion came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478031/168657))

Comment: `Font::TTF` is a nice module, but it requires some understanding of the TrueType and OpenType formats. BTW, `$font->{cmap}->ms_table` returns a hash that maps Unicode code points to glyph IDs. This hash should be easier to use than the array returned by `->reverse`.