# Python3 Check if Unicode Character is Not Present

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, unicode

I have a question in regards to finding if a unicode character is present in the font on the system.

```
>>> chr(9966)
'⛮'
>>> chr(9955)
'⛣'
>>> chr(9955) == chr(9966)
False
```

Basically, what I am trying to do, is to do a check where if the value is `⛣`. Is there any way in python to figure out if the value is `⛣`?

Edit: I now understand that unicode characters are not inherently defined or undefined. But, is there a way to check if a character exists in a certain font? I am on OS X.

Comment: It's not actually printing an empty string, it is printing the unicode character (which happens to not show up). On my system, I see a question mark in a box.

Comment: What do you mean with "undefined on the system"? Do you mean "not present in the font"? (For me, both characters show up fine, by the way).

Comment: This might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-font-supports

Comment: To clarify the above, you are *not* seeing 'a character that looks like a box' (which in itself is a valid Unicode character [`□`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm)). You are seeing the *default character* if the one asked for is not present in the font that is happened to be used for display. And usually, Python does not know what font your system is using so it cannot somehow 'change' the character to a box (which you seem to think it does), nor can it tell you if the character is available (unless you tell it what font gets used).

Comment: @alexis I'm on a mac

Comment: Hmm, your question was marked as a duplicate of a question about **Linux**. Do the solutions given there work for you?

Comment: @alexis not really. No

Comment: I have flagged the question for reopening, since the duplicate question is about Linux, and the answers do not work on OS X.

Comment: The Python fonttools lib does not work on OSX? Why not?

Comment: @alexis and Anthony: I just tested and can absolutely **confirm** that the solution in the duplicate **does work**. For `python font.py /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf 9966` the output is `GEAR WITH HANDLES False`. (You need to enable the commented-out part of that code.)

Comment: @RadLexus, that's good to know. This question still needs to be reopened, though, and you or someone else can explain what works from the other answers (I have a simpler solution, I think).

Comment: @alexis: since the solution in the duplicate works, the problem is at OPs side – it is *not* related to OP's OS being different. If you have another solution, you still can answer the original question, right?

Comment: Not if the solution is inapplicable to Linux-- it would be off-topic in the original question. (In any case, I don't have access to a linux system I can test on.)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the used font, and its support for Unicode, not python itself.
I don't have these characters on my system.

Using the library [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/), any unknown character seems to be returned as `[?]`:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(chr(9966))
'[?]'
>>> unidecode(chr(9955))
'[?]'
>>> unidecode(chr(9955)) == unidecode(chr(9966))
True
```

This method rely on appearance for get an ascii equivalent.
Some others Unicode characters can be found as close to `[?]`, so probably you will get some false positive.