How to display Unicode Power Symbols in my Jetpack Compose app?
I'm trying to get a little switch (segmented button) that shows Unicode PowerOn/PowerSleep symbols:
var selectedIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
val options = listOf("\u23fd", "\u23fe")
SingleChoiceSegmentedButtonRow(modifier = Modifier
    .width(80.dp)
    .height(40.dp)) {
        options.forEachIndexed { index, label ->
            SegmentedButton(shape = SegmentedButtonDefaults.itemShape(index = index, count = options.size),
                colors = SegmentedButtonDefaults.colors(activeContainerColor = Color.DarkGray, activeContentColor = Color.White),
                onClick = { selectedIndex = index },
                selected = selectedIndex == index,
                icon = {}) {
                Text(label)
        }
}
    

Sadly, I just end up with

How can I find (and use) a font that will display these correctly?

possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-given-font-supports

As an alternative you could use Icons instead: https://fonts.google.com/icons. For example Icons.Default.PowerSettingsNew and Icons.Default.Bedtime.
